# could not convert '(<expression error>)' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to std::unique_ptr<int []>

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I have the latest gcc compiler.
gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~14.04) 6.2.0

On code::blocks I've set the compiler to the GNU Compiler as default.

The error I'm getting is this

> error: could not convert `{<expression error>}` from `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to `std::unique_ptr<int []>`

The issue is in my header file at the bottom.

This was for a lab that I did in class and It worked fine last week I think - compiling the header file gives me my results but when i build from the arrayclass.cpp file it gives me this error.

Here is my implementation file ArrayClass.cpp:

```
#include "ArrayClass.h"

#include <memory>

using std::make_unique;

ArrayClass::ArrayClass(int capacity)
  : arrSize{capacity},
    arr{make_unique<int[]>(capacity)}
{
}

void ArrayClass::insert(int value)
{
    if (currentSize < arrSize) {
        arr[currentSize++] =  value;
    }
}

void ArrayClass::set(int i, int value)
{
    if (i >= 0 && i < currentSize) {
        arr[i] =  value;
    }
}

int ArrayClass::get(int i) const
{
    if (i >= 0 && i < currentSize) {
        return arr[i];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int ArrayClass::capacity() const
{
    return arrSize;
}

int ArrayClass::size() const
{
    return currentSize;
}
```

And here is my header file:

```
#ifndef ArrayClass_header
#define ArrayClass_header
#include <memory>

using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;

class ArrayClass
{
public:
    // Constructors and Destructors

    // Default constructor
    // POST: Created an ArrayClass object with an array of size def_size
    // Compiler default suffices (see variable initializations at end of header)
    ArrayClass() = default;

    // Constructor
    // PRE: capacity > 0
    // POST: Created an ArrayClass object with an array of size capacity
    // PARAM: capacity = size of the array to allocate
    ArrayClass(int capacity);

    // Destructor
    // POST: All dynamic memory associated with object de-allocated
  //  ~ArrayClass();

    // Set the value of the next free element
    // PRE: currentSize < arraySize
    // POST: Element at index currentSize set to value
    // PARAM: value = value to be set
    void insert(int value);

    // Return an element's value
    // PRE: 0 <= i < arraySize
    // POST: Returned the value at index i
    // PARAM: i = index of value to be returned
    int get(int i) const;

    // Set an element's value
    // PRE: 0 <= i < arraySize
    // POST: Element at index i set to value
    // PARAM: i = index of element to be changed
    //        value = value to be set
    void set(int i, int value);

    // POST: Return the currently allocated space
    int capacity() const;

    // POST: Return the number of elements
    int size() const;

    // The default capacity
    static constexpr int def_capacity {10};

private:
    int arrSize {def_capacity};
    int currentSize {0};
    unique_ptr<int[]> arr {make_unique<int[]>(capacity)};
};

#endif
```

Comment: It's good style to not put the `using` declarations in the header, in case someone wants to use your header but not have those `using`s

Comment: Have voted to close as typo, since the problem is just a missing `def_`.

Comment: I'll take note of that as well, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error is here:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> arr {make_unique<int[]>(capacity)};
```

`capacity` should be `def_capacity` instead, since as of now, you're using the name of a function but without the round parentheses, which makes the compiler stumble while parsing the `{}` initializer list.

**Edit**: Yes, it compiles fine with the fix. There are two errors, the first one being "*invalid use of non-static member function* `int ArrayClass::capacity() const`". Then the initializer-list one follows, since the compiler can't parse the initalizer list.

**Edit 2**: In the `.cpp` file, in the constructor definition, `capacity` appears to shadow the `ArrayClass::capacity()` function, but I still think it'd be better to avoid such a collision just for clarity sake.

Comment: Yea, it compiled after your fix - so if i understand correctly, the allocation of the int array requires an int value and I fed it a variable instead so the compiler got mad at me and told me that I can't do that.

Comment: Also  `int ArrayClass::capacity() const` doesn't seem to be an error after the fix so two birds with one stone? (also thank you!)

Comment: What you did what to feed a *function name* not even a call since it was without the parens. That in itself is  compiler error, to use the func name like that in this context. As far as the const vs variable, I know little C++14, but I think you'd need to declare `ArrayClass::capacily()` as `constexpr` to be able to use it here.

Comment: Oh yes right capacity() is one of my defined functions.

Comment: A function name without parens would've been alright if you were taking its address to save it in a function pointer, to be exact. The first error is exactly for the missing parens.

Comment: You're right about that constexpr as well - i did the for def_capacity. 

Okay well things are fine and dandy now and I understand the problem/solution. Thank you for your help :)